# Are iterators valid after sorting or removing elements? Is this code a ticking time bomb?

Tags: c++, qt, iterator

I just wanted to ask if iterators are valid after **sorting** or **removal** of elements. When we insert into a container, it can be reallocated to find more space and invalidate existing iterators. But what happens with sorting and removal of elements? Can those force the container to be reallocated?

Is this code going to crash once?

```
QVector<Foo> container;

b = container.begin();
e = container.end();

while (container.count() > newCount)
{
    computeSomePropertyOfFoo(b, e);  // Computes property between b and e
    sortByThatProperty(b, e);        // sorts members between b and e
    container.erase(--e);
}
```

Comment: In general, the only way to know things like this is to check the documentation. (or the source code, in a pinch)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Container Classes](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/containers.html) documentation:

> #### The Iterator Classes
>
> Iterators provide a uniform means to access items in a container. Qt's container classes provide two types of iterators: Java-style iterators and STL-style iterators. *Iterators of both types are invalidated when the data in the container is modified* or detached from implicitly shared copies due to a call to a non-const member function.

So yes, your code is incorrect. You shouldn't "cache" the iterators the way you do it.

Comment: Worth noting that QVector::erase returns a valid iterator to the next element, so one can do "it = vector.erase( it )" to remove while iterating.

Comment: Well it is useless in this case, as e and b is invalid, after "sortByThatProperty"